# Basic ImGui program doesn't render, leaks memory and crashes

Tags: cocoa, glfw, metal, objective-c++, imgui

I'm trying to create the most basic example program using ImGui, GLFW and the Metal API.

This is my code:

```
// main.mm

#include <iostream>

#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#define GLFW_EXPOSE_NATIVE_COCOA
#include <GLFW/glfw3native.h>
#include <imgui.h>
#include <backends/imgui_impl_osx.h>
#include <backends/imgui_impl_metal.h>
#include <Metal/Metal.h>
#include <QuartzCore/CAMetalLayer.h>

int main() {
    if (!glfwInit()) {
        std::cout << "Failed to init GLFW\n";
        return 1;
    }
    auto* W = glfwCreateWindow(1000, 800, "My Window", nullptr, nullptr);
    if (!W) {
        std::cout << "Failed to create window\n";
        return 1;
    }
    int width = 0, height = 0;
    glfwGetWindowSize(W, &width, &height);
    ImGui::CreateContext();
    NSWindow* NSW = glfwGetCocoaWindow(W);
    ImGui_ImplOSX_Init(NSW.contentView);
    id<MTLDevice> device = MTLCreateSystemDefaultDevice();
    ImGui_ImplMetal_Init(device);
    CAMetalLayer* layer = [[CAMetalLayer alloc] init];
    layer.device = device;
    layer.pixelFormat = MTLPixelFormatBGRA8Unorm;
    layer.drawableSize = CGSize{ 2.0 * width, 2.0 * height };
    NSW.contentView.wantsLayer = true;
    [NSW.contentView setLayer:layer];
    id commandQueue = [device newCommandQueue];
    ImGui_ImplMetal_CreateFontsTexture(device);
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(W)) {
        ImGuiIO& io = ImGui::GetIO();
        io.DisplaySize = ImVec2(width, height);
        ImGui_ImplOSX_NewFrame(NSW.contentView);
        ImGui::NewFrame();
        
        // User code
        ImGui::ShowDemoWindow();
        
        id<MTLCommandBuffer> commandBuffer = [commandQueue commandBuffer];
        MTLRenderPassDescriptor* renderPassDescriptor = [[MTLRenderPassDescriptor alloc] init];
        MTLRenderPassColorAttachmentDescriptor* caDesc = [[MTLRenderPassColorAttachmentDescriptor alloc] init];
        id<CAMetalDrawable> drawable = layer.nextDrawable;
        caDesc.texture = drawable.texture;
        caDesc.loadAction = MTLLoadActionClear;
        caDesc.storeAction = MTLStoreActionStore;
        [renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments setObject: caDesc
                                      atIndexedSubscript: 0];
        ImGui_ImplMetal_NewFrame(renderPassDescriptor);
        
        // Rendering
        ImGui::Render();
        ImDrawData* drawData = ImGui::GetDrawData();
        renderPassDescriptor.colorAttachments[0].clearColor = MTLClearColorMake(1, 0, 1, 1);
        id <MTLRenderCommandEncoder> renderEncoder = [commandBuffer renderCommandEncoderWithDescriptor:renderPassDescriptor];
        [renderEncoder pushDebugGroup:@"Dear ImGui rendering"];
        ImGui_ImplMetal_RenderDrawData(drawData, commandBuffer, renderEncoder);
        [renderEncoder popDebugGroup];
        [renderEncoder endEncoding];
        // Present
        [commandBuffer presentDrawable: drawable];
        [commandBuffer commit];
        [drawable present];
        
        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    ImGui_ImplMetal_Shutdown();
    ImGui_ImplOSX_Shutdown();
}
```

This creates a window that I can interact with. But that's about it. The window is black, the program leaks memory like crazy (after 3 seconds it uses 3GB of memory), it draws between 300 and 3000 frames per second and crashes after a few more seconds in a function called

```
layer_private_present_impl(_CAMetalLayerPrivate*, CAMetalDrawable*, double, unsigned int)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess this isn't the greatest SO question but I'm kind of desperate

Comment: Can you share your cmake file or the whole project as a link? It's kinda cumbersome to try to set it up the same way you might have done.

Comment: @Spo1ler Sure: https://github.com/chrysante/imgui-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your case:

1. The code is written in a way that assumes that Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) is enabled, but it's not enabled in the project settings, at least in the link you attached in the comment.
2. You are missing `@autoreleasepool { ... }` around the body of the `while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(W))`. If you add autoreleasepool, it will work, kinda.

Just to be clear, to fix this example, you don't need to do 1, just add an autoreleasepool.

But you really need to enable ARC. You can do so by going into project settings and enabling `Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting` or by enabling this Xcode setting `CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC = NO`. Or you can also pass `-fobjc-arc` compiler option.

Comment: Thank you! But it only solves half the problem. ARC is already enabled in the cmake script, at least for the executable target. Adding `@autoreleasepool` around the loop body gets rid of the memory leak, but it still segfaults after a few seconds in the `layer_private_present_impl` function.

Comment: And I just discovered the weirdest behaviour: I'm making this project to create a minimal example of a bug in a bigger project. And if I run that other program in the background, the minimal example works just as expected UNTIL I move the window.  Then the window goes black, the framerate goes up and the program segfaults. If I don't run the other program in the background it crashes directly.

Comment: And the program is reporting a new error at runtime: "flock failed to lock list file (/var/folders/47/9yzc4ndj2rv9jm5ww8k_0g000000gn/C//com.apple.metal/16777236_6003/functions.list): errno = 35" -- I hope this is not too spammy, thanks for your help!

Comment: The last error is kinda irrelevant, it has something to do with shader cache, not sure what. Otherwise, could you update your sample and specify exactly how you build it.

Comment: I updated the repo. I generate an XCode project with the cmake script and run the `imgui-test` target in Debug mode from the IDE under the debugger.

Comment: Can't promise anything, but I'll try to take a look

Comment: I figured it out, I have to call `glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CLIENT_API, GLFW_NO_API)` before creating the window, otherwise GLFW will try to make the window use OpenGL for rendering.